# infinispan-query is not importing with maven

Tags: java, maven, infinispan

Hi I'm trying out to import infinispan-query dependency to my project.

```
<version.infinispan>5.2.8.Final</version.infinispan>
<version.infinispan-query>5.2.8.Final</version.infinispan-query>
................
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.infinispan/infinispan-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
            <artifactId>infinispan-core</artifactId>
            <version>${version.infinispan}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.infinispan/infinispan-query -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
            <artifactId>infinispan-query</artifactId>
            <version>${version.infinispan-query}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Here is part of my pom.xml where I've added the dependencies, the infinispan-core dependency it's imported, but I don't know why the infinispan-query dependency it's not imported.

Any help please? Thanks!

Comment: Try `maven with `-U` flag to force download of previously failed packages that will not be reattempted in next couple hours

Comment: Thanks for comment, but not working V_V.

Comment: What is maven saying when it tries to download it ?

Comment: I've added the dependency directly in the pom's module where I want to use it and then has been downloaded. I don't know why if I put the dependency in my core's pom it's not working.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that it perhaps was in <dependencyManagement> section?

Comment: Yes, you're right!

Answer (score 1):

You might try to add [JBoss Public Repository](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/public-jboss) to your pom (or settings.xml). Both artifacts seem to be there ([infinispan-core](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/public-jboss/org/infinispan/infinispan-core/5.2.8.Final/), [infinispan-query](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/public-jboss/org/infinispan/infinispan-query/5.2.8.Final/)). More information how to do that you might find in [Maven's Guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html).